# how to return two different mocks from same function depending on passed parameters in mockk?

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, mockk

I am testing one method.
It requests the same function of a mocked object twice but with different parameters passed. Naturally, I need two different answers, but mockk gives me the same answer for both.

```
every { userRepository.getUser("A") }.answers { userA }
every { userRepository.getUser("B") }.answers { userB }
```

How can I get two different results using mockk?

Comment: Can you post more code of the test and implementation. Also you can uses returns instead of answers if all you are doing is returning values.

Comment: my stubs were set up incorrectly. The code I wrote above works like a charm.

Answer (score 7):

As stated in the comment to the question, this can be achieved simply by specifying the parameters.

However, if the condition is more involved, the same thing can be achieved by capturing slots.

For example if we wanted to return `42` if the user's id was `1`, and `35` otherwise:

```
val userSlot = slot<User>()
every { userRepository.saveUser(capture(userSlot)) } answers {
  if (userSlot.captured.id == 1) 42
  else 35
}
```